# How do I submit my form using href?

Tags: php, javascript, html, anchor

Am using this `onclick='document.forms['form_name'].submit(); return false;'` but this doesn't work as am having `href=results.php?page_no=1` etc, has dynamic links, examples show to make this work I need to use `href="#"` but any idea how I can submit the form and than navigate to `page2`? Because I want to save the check box values in a session

Comment: page2 should be set as form action, then, I think you can do it.

Comment: So on submit, you want to follow the action or ignore the action and follow the javascript?

Comment: I've not set any action as I said am using this in a pagination so I cannot define any action here

Comment: You want to POST the form, then NOT wait for the response, then go to another page?  Doesn't sound like a good design.  Why not have the result of the POST do a redirect on success?

Comment: @SteveH. am using this to check rows inside a pagination, got it? so I don't need to check for any success, the moment user clicks the link of next page, it should add the values in the session array and later I check whether the values are in array and I echo checked

Comment: @SteveH. I didn't meant got in in a wrong way :)

Comment: Sorry, having a hard time understanding: "but this doesn't work as am having href=results.php?page_no=1 etc, has dynamic links,".  What does this collection of sentence fragments mean?  Describe your problem using complete sentences with subjects, verbs and predicates.

Comment: @SteveH. See it's a PHP navigation, which has simple next and previous page links, it has links like home.php?page=1, when you click on next you get home.php?page=2 etc, so here I am using check boxes to check rows, so when user navigates I want to remember the checkboxes he ticked and hence I want to submit the form when user clicks on next and he should be navigated to next page, I hope this clears your doubts :)

Comment: That helps.  There's nothing about that that requires JavaScript, BTW.  The normal form submission will include all the inputs in the form.  You can read the checkboxes on the server side.

Comment: @SteveH. am already doing that that but the issue is how do I navigate him to another page as I cannot set action as he can come from page 21 to page 1 directly so..

Answer (score 2):

Add class to your hrefs (class="pagination") and id (id="form") to your form. Then you can use Jquery framework for this stuff.

```
$(".pagination").click(function(){  
// get page id, set form action with params
$("#formId").submit();

return false;  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but I am not able to navigate, this does submit but doesnt go to the next page, any idea why? +1

Comment: And what do you mean with navigate? Just redirect?

Comment: Am using href so actually the form should be submitted and should be then navigated, I cant use action here so I need href to work

Comment: Try that new line. But i dont think this can be possible anyway. Because you will send form by submiting. This make you HTTP request, and page will load again.

Comment: But you can send Ajax request and then change location. This will save your session or anything you can want in that request.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24399/discussion-between-tom-and-acidic-cloud)

Answer (score 0):

Here I substituted page2 with Google just for test

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.forms['test'].submit(); return false;">Submit</a>
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search?q=test" name="test">
<input name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
</form>
```

edit:

```
<a href="page2.php?page=2" onclick="document.test.action =encodeURIComponent(this.getAttribute('href')); document.forms['test'].submit(); return false;">Submit</a>
<form method="get" action="" name="test">
<input name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
</form>
```

without encodeURIComponent(this.getAttribute('href') the parameters are missed.

Comment: There's no page2, I said it's dynamic so only GET variable value changes :)

Comment: then I am not understanding your requirement

Comment: don't know if it is a language issue or not, but I'm sensing attitude...  Have a downvote...  Use more words, rather than terse sentences and you may get more help.

Comment: @SteveH. Where you saw attitude in any of my sentence?

Comment: @AcidicCloud: check second one

Comment: did you changed the form attributes? can you show me your trial?

Comment: @Akam just wait I didn't changed your test

Comment: @Akam this is spoiling the URL, you are adding the URL to the current URL, I guess this is close

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad design.

You can't perform multiple competing actions on a form click and expect it to work.

You need to either let the link be clicked and let it load another page, or if you are just setting some session variable (although it would be far better to set this with a querystring parameter or a cookie), you can use an Ajax request to send that off asynchronously.

Comment: Actually I don't know Ajax or JavaScript as am a server side programmer so am stucked

Comment: Well this is a great place to learn Ajax and JavaScript. You're trying to solve a problem with the wrong tools. You've made admirable progress, but save yourself some headache and do this through the UI.

Comment: Ya I guess I should wait for a better solution, Tom's answer works for me but it is not allowing me to navigate to another page

Comment: Tom's answer has invalid syntax, so if it is working for you, it is only by accident. You could likely completely remove his code and achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

**Some options:**

1) Use jQuery AJAX, serialize and post the form data and then redirect (location.href) on the onSuccess callback. Something like this:

```
$.post("submitform.php", 
       $("form").serialize(),  
       function(data){location.href='results.php?page_no=2';}
      );
```

2) Post the form to a named hidden iFrame using "target" on the form tag. If this is really just a best effort sort of recording you shouldn't need to wait for the page to load, the request should be enough and you can continue to the next page. Something like this:

```
<iframe="targetname" style="display:none;" />
<form name="myform" target="targetname" method="post" action="submitform.php">
....
</form>
<a href="page2.php" onClick="document.forms['myform'].submit(); return true;">
Click Here
</a>
```